# Visual glitch in a three.js animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, webgl

I am currently coding an animation using three.js (r76) and, while everything works fine on my computer, a friend got a visual glitch when running it.
The object leaves a trace upon rotation, as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Here is a MWE, able to reproduce the bug.

```js
var camera, scene, group, renderer, container, stats;

var width = 450;
var height = 400;
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(-1, -1);
var clic = false;
var mouseGlob = new THREE.Vector2();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var pause = false;
var inters = 0;

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene()
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-width/2, width/2, -height/2, height/2, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 300;
    scene.add(camera);

    atomRadius = 50;
    var segments = 15,
        rings = 15,
        bondLength = 2*atomRadius*1.5
        bondRadius = 10,
        atomPos = bondLength/Math.sqrt(3);
    var atom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(atomRadius, segments, rings);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x6f919a,wireframe:true, opacity:0.8});
    var flash = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000,wireframe:true});
    
    var atomC = new THREE.Mesh(atom, material.clone());
    
    atomCl1 = new THREE.Mesh(atom, material.clone());
    atomCl1.position.set(atomPos,atomPos,atomPos);
    
    atomCl2 = new THREE.Mesh(atom, material.clone());
    atomCl2.position.set(atomPos,-atomPos,-atomPos);
    
   group = new THREE.Object3D();
    group.add(atomC);
    group.add(atomCl1);
    group.add(atomCl2);
    
    scene.add(group);
    
    container = document.getElementById('plan').getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: container, alpha: true});
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    
    container.onmouseout = function(event){pause = false;};
    container.onmouseover = function(){pause = true;};
    stats = new Stats();
    document.getElementById('plan').appendChild(stats.domElement);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
    stats.update();
}

function render() {
    if(!pause) {
        group.rotation.x += .004;
        group.rotation.y += .008;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r76/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/r16/Stats.min.js"></script>
<div id="plan">
<canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

This glitch appears on both of his computers, using Firefox 47.0.1 on Windows 7, with an Intel HD Graphics 4000. The animation runs at 60 FPS.

I had this animation tested by 5 other people (including myself) in Google Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari and Safari for iOs on Windows 7, Windows 10, Ubuntu 14.04 and Mac OS X and we could not reproduce this glitch.

I could not find any related problem on Google or SO as I wasn't able to correctly describe the problem in my searches.

Does anyone know the origin of this problem and how I can solve it ?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: My guess is win 7 intel drivers are trying to cope with alpha:true.  If you do not need it transparent, I would not make it alpha true anyways.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. I removed the `alpha: true` and the animation runs flawlessly. I also had to give up the `opacity: 0.8`, but that's nothing compared to a bug-free animation. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea if this would work but, on thinking about this, if you need it to be transparent, try placing the content that goes behind the 3d canvas in its own div (even if it's just background color) and giving it a css transform value such as translateZ(0). Each browser has its own css translate syntax. This may trigger a webGL render on all assets and help the browser paint properly. If that doesn't work, I would try putting all assets inside the same div and put the translateZ on the parent div.

Comment: That's a clever workaround.  
But in my case, I have no background content. The `opacity: 0.8` is in the sphere material definition ; I'll just put a lighter color and that will do the trick.